# Definition of $I(\varphi, M)$ in Buchsbaum's and Eisenbud's "What makes a complex exact?"

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

In their paper *What makes a complex exact?*, Buchsbaum and Eisenbud define an ideal $I(\varphi, M)$, where $M$ is a module over a commutative ring, and $\varphi: F \to G$ is a homomorphism of projective $R$-modules. I'm not sure that I understand the definition correctly. First they define $I(\varphi)$ to be the image of the induced morphism
$$(\Lambda^k G)^* \otimes \Lambda^kF \to R, \tag{$*$}$$
for $k = \operatorname{rank}(\varphi)$, that is the smallest $k$ such that $0 \neq \Lambda^k \varphi: \Lambda^k F \to \Lambda^k G$.
Then they write

> Similarly, if $M$ is an $R$-module, we define $I(\varphi, M)$ to be the image of the above map where $k = \operatorname{rank}(\varphi, M)$.

So is $\operatorname{rank}(\varphi, M)$ really the only property of $M$ that enters into the definition of $I(\varphi, M)$? Or do I have to tensorize something in $(*)$ by $M$? This is somehow also suggested in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336542/inverting-a-nonzerodivisor-on-a-module), though it's not the point of discussion there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think that the image of $(\Lambda^k G)^* \otimes \Lambda^kF \to R$ is the same as the image of $(\Lambda^k G \otimes M)^* \otimes (\Lambda^kF \otimes M)\to R$, at least if $k = \operatorname{rank}(\varphi, M)$. The reason here is that the canonical map $M^* \otimes M \to R$ is surjective.